# DateTime range separators with JavaScript work for all but a few ranges

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, datetime

I have a JSON sting of `Activity Records` from a database that I iterate over and print to screen.

Using the creation DateTime on each record, I pass them through a simple Date comparison function which takes a `start date`, `end date`, and the `date to see if it is in the range between the other 2`

The goal is to insert a divider between the records with something like:

```
'A while Ago': [],
'Last Month': [],
'Earliar in the Month': [],
'Last Week': [],
'Earlier this Week': [],
'Yesterday': [],
'Today': [],
```

So I have an almost working demo here http://jsfiddle.net/jasondavis/0vsz8jk4/18/

This image shows the problem area... I have 20 test records and it stops at record 16 below.  Also I have records that should fit in `Earlier this week` and `Yesterday` however you can see on the demo JSFiddle they are empty!

Also they aren't empty because those records are being stolen by another date range group but simply do not show up.  Records 17, 18, 19, and 20 are gone!

Any ideas to fix?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Records 17,18,19 and 20 presumably don't fall into any of the date ranges defined in `dateRangeLabels` - for instance, in the fiddle you posted, I got up to record 18, so presumably the date ranges are not the same in the fiddle as in the code you are testing

Records 19 and 20 were not in any defined date range - 19 because the code has today = 12th, yesterday = 11th and "earlier in the week" as 5th to 9th ... record 19 being the 10th falls in to no range and therefore "dropped".

record 20 is the 17th, again, does not fall into any defined range, so gets "dropped"

see working fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/0vsz8jk4/19/

All I've changed is - make sure earlier in the week includes two days ago (which you didn't), add 'other' which is from tomorrow to year 2999 (there's better ways to do it, but I just wanted to show you that your code works, you just had minor issues)

Comment: Hey thats great.  I have literally posted 3-04 posts on here trying to get help in how to build this functionality and I just finalyl got this far.  I had no idea how to inject these date divers in-between my records.   I have the Date utility function which makes it easy to determine if a record falls in between 2 dates but I didn't know how to actually get it to what it is now.  So I would be super excited and grateful if you care to show any other methods of doing this.